# MPAndroidChart: How To Have Draggable Data Entries

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart

I am working on creating an app that allows someone to control a motorized camera slider. I am implementing MPAndroidChart as the base of my position as a function of time graph. I am able to allow users to add a "keyframe" (an Entry in MPAndroidChart terms) by double tapping somewhere on the LineChart; however, for functionality sake the user should also be able to select an existing keyframe and move it by dragging the keyframe to wherever they would like it to be. My question is how do I implement that with MPAndroidChart? Below is my current code for the project.

```
package com.emotion.slider.activities

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.emotion.slider.R
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet
import com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.ChartTouchListener
import com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.OnChartGestureListener
import com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.OnChartValueSelectedListener
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.EntryXComparator
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.mainactivity.*
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
    OnChartGestureListener, OnChartValueSelectedListener{
    private val TAG = "Main Activity"
    lateinit var chart: LineChart   // LineChart is initialized From XML
    var keyFrames_TrackSlide = ArrayList<Entry>()

    override fun onChartGestureStart(
        me: MotionEvent?,
        lastPerformedGesture: ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture?
    ) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onChartGestureStart: X: " + me?.getX() + "Y: " + me?.getY())
    }

    override fun onChartGestureEnd(
        me: MotionEvent?,
        lastPerformedGesture: ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture?
    ) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onChartGestureEnd: $lastPerformedGesture")
    }

    override fun onChartScale(me: MotionEvent?, scaleX: Float, scaleY: Float) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onChartScale: Scale-X: $scaleX Scale-Y: $scaleY")
    }

    override fun onChartLongPressed(me: MotionEvent?) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onChartLongPressed: ")
    }

    override fun onChartSingleTapped(me: MotionEvent?) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onChartSingleTapped: ")
    }

    override fun onChartDoubleTapped(me: MotionEvent?) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onChartDoubleTapped: " + me.toString())

        // Convert Position Of Double Tap To A Point On The Graph
        var x: Float? = me?.x                                                                                   // Grab the X-Coordinate
        var y: Float? = me?.y                                                                                   // Grab the y-Coordinate
        var newTouchPoint = chart.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT).getValuesByTouchPoint(x!!, y!!)     // Create a New Touch Point From The X and Y Coordinates (Will Map Raw Data To A Point On The Graph)
        var xValue = newTouchPoint.x
        var yValue = newTouchPoint.y
        var xValueRounded = "%.2f".format(xValue).toFloat()
        var yValueRounded = "%.2f".format(yValue).toFloat()
        var newEntry = Entry(xValueRounded, yValueRounded)

        Log.i(TAG, "ValueX: $xValueRounded, ValueY: $yValueRounded")

        // Grab Pre-Existing Data (Points) From Chart
        var chartDataPoints = chart.data
        if (chartDataPoints == null){
            chartDataPoints = LineData()
            chart.data = chartDataPoints
        }

        keyFrames_TrackSlide.add( newEntry)
        Collections.sort(keyFrames_TrackSlide, EntryXComparator())
        chart.data.clearValues()
        var set1 = LineDataSet(keyFrames_TrackSlide, "Data Set 1")
        set1.fillAlpha = 110
        var dataSets = ArrayList<ILineDataSet>()
        dataSets.add(set1)
        var data = LineData(dataSets)
        chart.data = data

        chartDataPoints.notifyDataChanged()
        chart.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

    override fun onChartFling(
        me1: MotionEvent?,
        me2: MotionEvent?,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float
    ) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onChartDoubleFling: Velocity-X: $velocityX Velocity-Y: $velocityY")
    }

    override fun onChartTranslate(me: MotionEvent?, dX: Float, dY: Float) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onChartTranslate: dX: $dX dy: $dY")
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onNothingSelected: ")
    }

    override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry?, h: Highlight?) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onValueSelected: " + e.toString())

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity)
        createLineGraph()                       // Creates The Line Graph

    }

    private fun createLineGraph(){
        // Setup LineChart From XML
        chart = this.lineChartFromXML                                   // Grab LineChart from XML
        chart.isScaleYEnabled = false                                   // Don't Allow User To Scale On Y-Axis
        chart.isScaleXEnabled = true                                    // Allow User To Scale On X-Axis
        chart.legend.isEnabled = false                                  // Disable The Chart's Legend (We'll provide our own)
        chart.maxHighlightDistance = 50.0f                              // Sets The max distance away a touch can be from a keyframe in order to access/modify the keyframe
        chart.isDoubleTapToZoomEnabled = false                          // Disable The Double Tap To Zoom Feature (We'll use double tap to signify a new keyframe)
        chart.onChartGestureListener = this@MainActivity                // This Activity will be able to handle gestures from User input
        chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this@MainActivity)        // This activity will allow for the value selector listener to work

        // Setup Right Y-Axis' Settings
        val rightYAxis = chart.axisRight                                // Grab The LineChart's Right Y-Axis Object
        rightYAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)                              // Don't show grid lines on right side of Y-Axis
        rightYAxis.axisMaximum = 180F                                   // Set The Maximum Of The Right Y-Axis to be 180
        rightYAxis.axisMinimum = -180F                                  // Set The Minimum Of The Right Y-Axis to be -180
        rightYAxis.setLabelCount(5, true)                  // Show 5 Labels On The Right Y-Axis
        rightYAxis.textSize = 12.0f                                     // Set Label Size


        // Setup Left Axis' Settings
        val leftYAxis = chart.axisLeft                                  // Grab The LineChart's Left  Y-Axis Object
        leftYAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)                               // Don't show grid lines on left side of Y-Axis
        leftYAxis.axisMaximum = 180F                                    // Set The Maximum Of The Left Y-Axis to be 180
        leftYAxis.axisMinimum = -180F                                   // Set The Minimum Of The Left Y-Axis to be -180
        leftYAxis.setDrawLabels(false)                                  // Don't draw any labels on the Left Y-Axis


        // Setup X-Axis' Settings
        val xAxis = chart.xAxis                                         // Grab The LineChart's X-Axis Object
        xAxis.axisMinimum = 0F                                          // Set X-Axis' Minimum To 0 (seconds)
        xAxis.axisMaximum = 6F                                          // Set X-Axis' Maximum to 6 (seconds)
        xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM                     // Set The Labels of the X-Axis to be on the bottom of the X-Axis
        xAxis.textSize = 12.0f                                          // Set Label Size


        // THE FOLLOWING IS PUTTING ENTRIES INTO AN ARRAY OF ENTRIES, WHICH THEN BECOMES AN ARRAY OF
        // DATA SETS, WHICH THEN BECOMES LINE DATA, WHICH THEN GETS ASSIGNED TO THE XML's LINE CHART,
        // FINALLY- THE VIEWER IS REFRESHED.

        // Step 1.) Create Entries With Position NOT Changing Over Time (Initial Chart's Keyframes)
        keyFrames_TrackSlide.add(Entry(0f, 0f))  // Time = 0 Sec, Position = Origin
        keyFrames_TrackSlide.add(Entry(6f, 0f))  // Time = 6 Sec, Position = Origin

        // Step 2.) Create a LineDataSet from the given Entries
        var dataSetTrackSlide = LineDataSet(keyFrames_TrackSlide, "TrackSlide")

        // Step 3.) Create an Array of the DataSets
        var dataSets = ArrayList<ILineDataSet>()
        dataSets.add(dataSetTrackSlide)

        // Step 4.) Create a LineData object from the DataSet Array
        var data = LineData(dataSets)

        // Step 5.) Assign The LineData to the chart from the XML
        chart.data = data

        // Step 6.) Refresh the XML view by calling invalidate()
        chart.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Figured it out, created a new class that would implement a few things: [KOTLIN]

   ```
    class myChartTouchListener() : Activity(), OnTouchListener, 
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{
        // Code For Class Goes Here, Implement All Necessary Functions
    }
   ```
2. Called it from main activity passing my view which holds MPAndroidChart

   ```
    // Set My onTouchListener for any touches on the MPAndroidChart
    this.lineChartFromXML.setOnTouchListener(myChartTouchListener())
   ```